Are there any platforms similar to off2class.com for learning German?
When I was learning English, teachers from italki (a platform to find an online language teacher) introduced me to the platform off2class.com, which I found very useful. There is a placement test consisting of 100 questions. By having two accounts for myself (teacher + student), I could identify all the weak aspects of my English from the results of the placement test. The platform automatically suggests lessons and checks them afterward for those grammar rules I had problems with. Off2class also has a free account option. But the paid one is also affordable. Tried both.
This way, I was able to have focused solo study of English with high efficiency.
For the German language, I wish there were such a platform as well. For now, the closest thing I found is: https://learngerman.dw.com, which is also nice. It has a progress tracker, and the learning program is of very high quality and completely free.
But maybe there is a platform I am not aware of that is very similar to off2class?
